# Sitecore - Custom Search Dialog

Tags: xml, sitecore, sitecore6

I am creating a custom search screen accessed from the Sitecore content editor via a custom context menu. This is working - I have created a custom XML dialog that allows users to do a search query on a external system this also is working fine. The problem is displaying my custom search results (a list of custom objects) returned from the external system into a grid panel or something similar.  I am totally new to XML and haven't been able to figure this out. I'm sure I am missing something obvious!

The gridpanel I want to bind to:

```
        <GridPanel ID="myGridPanel" Columns="2">
           <GridPanel.ColumnStyles>
            <Column Width="70%" />
            <Column Width="30%" />
           </GridPanel.ColumnStyles>

         <GridPanel.RowStyles>
           <Row Height="100%" />
         </GridPanel.RowStyles>
       </GridPanel>
```

The method where the binding should occur:

```
 private void BindExternalDocumentsToDataGrid(List<ExternalRecord> recordsFromExternalSystem)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(recordsFromExternalSystem, "There are no records for display!!");
        foreach (ExternalRecord record in recordsFromExternalSystem)
        {
           //How can I bind to my gridpanel? 
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridPanel` inherits the `DataSource` property from WebControl and implements the DataBind method.